# Nuances and context of linking without 〜て / dropped 「て」in linked constructions

Tags: grammar, meaning, nuances

(Taken from ジョジョの奇妙な冒険６部: When Jotaro talks to Jolyne about who got her into prison.../ for those who do not know the series: The persons speaking to each other are father and daughter but have a rather bad relationship)

> 「おまえに殺人の罪を**被せ**この刑務所に入れたのはロメオとかいうボーイフレンドではない」

The "shortend" **「〜て」** form makes me wonder here (if it actually is what I suppose it is).
In a similar question this construction of linking sentence constituents together by using the **「〜て」** form and dropping the **「〜て」** it was stated that this is rather used in formal/academic speech; however the context here doesn't seem to fit into the rage of academic contexts...

Is this 「**被せ」** a different construction or do I overestimate the academic nuance of dropping **「て」** in linked constructions.

Comment: Duplicate of https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/70321/removal-of-%e3%81%a6-in-japanese-novels/70324#70324 ?

Comment: Not a duplicate, but a related post describing some of what て adds: [Can adverbs modify adjectives?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/72061/can-adverbs-modify-adjectives/72065#72065)